# statying on the same page after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying to submit data to database without  redirecting the page.is there any error in this code?

```
$('#saving').on('click', function() { 
        var fname = $('#fname').val(); 
        var lname = $('#lname').val(); 
        var company = $('#company').val(); 
        var mnum = $('#mnum').val(); 
        var dataString = 'fname=' +fname + '&lname=' + lname + '&company=' + company + '&mnum=' + mnum; 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "submit.php", 
            data: dataString, 
            success: function() { 
                alert(''); 
                $('#dialog-message').dialog('open'); 
            } 
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want [`preventDefault`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/):

```
function(event) {
    // ... ajax ...
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The documentation states:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

Comment: And what shuld be the ajax code written inside.I am not familiar much with ajax.pls help me

Comment: the `... ajax ...` in my answer means that you should use your existing code, which seems fine. You can also provide the `data` argument as a javascript object, e.g. `{"fname": $('#fname').val()}`